# C sharp wpf как правильно собрать проект?

Tags: c#, wpf, компиляция

Помогите! Не могу собрать проект. Делаю релиз - у меня запускается, на 4 других машинах либо ошибка(на одной машине), либо совсем ничего.
Пришел к выводу, что не доложил что-то в проект. Пробовал собрать через ILMerge([хабростатья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/)). Получаю вот такую ошибку при компиляции:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MessagesDumperForVK, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  MessagesDumperForVK -> E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\MessagesDumperForVK.exe
1>      Start Release Merging MessagesDumperForVK.exe. 
1>  Target: "E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\MessagesDumperForVK.exe"
1>  target_dir: E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\
1>  Config: Release 
1>  Merging: '"""E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\"ILMerge\ILMerge.exe"" /wildcards /targetplatform:"v4, E:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /out:"E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\Output\MessagesDumperForVK.exe" "E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\MessagesDumperForVK.exe" "E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\*.dll"'
1>  An exception occurred during merging:
1>  Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: PresentationFramework.
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
1>     в System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
1>     в System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
1>     в System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
1>     в ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
1>     в ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
1>  Merge failed 
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command ""E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\ILMerge\merge_all.bat" "E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\" "E:\Users\DezmontDeXa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MessagesDumperForVK\MessagesDumperForVK\bin\Release\MessagesDumperForVK.exe" Release" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Выручайте) Желательно способ по проще. Видел пару статей, так там кода нужно больше чем у меня в программе...

Comment: "_либо ошибка(на одной машине)_" - Какая именно ошибка? Вы убедились, что на целевых машинах установлена необходимая версия NET Framework? Какие библиотеки в проекте используются, кроме стандартных? Вообще, чтобы доложить что-то в проект, не нужна никакая утилита: просто распространяйте необходимые DLL-файлы вместе с программой.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы решить проблему как есть, вы решили ее обойти с помощью `ILMerge`, который все только усложнил. Снесите его нафиг. Сделайте установочный пакет с помощью встроенной в VS утилиты - ClickOnce (прав.клик по проекту -> опубликовать), и будет вам счастье.

Comment: +за вариант от Bulson. В качестве альтернативы, использовать Wix для формирования инсталятора.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в WPF. Оказывается он в случае ошибки - крошится без единого намека на то что произошло. А произошло отсутствие frameworka нужной версии. Переделал по WFA - все сразу ок. При первом запуске на виртуалке - сказал, что не хватает ему 4.0 framework. Скачал поставил - попросил 4.6. После заработал как надо.

Проблема глубже. Я делал утилиту на заказ. Она возможно запуститься то всего 1 раз в жизни, после чего пропадет на каком-нибудь сдохшем винте. Потому делать для нее установщик - как то не практично.

Печально что без кучи строк кода не удастся сделать и красиво и с уведомлением - чего не хзватает.

Comment: Кстати, framework'и то были. Версия как у билда. Но видимо версия - версии рознь.

Comment: Бессмысленные сообщения об ошибке при отсутствии ключевого компонента, необходимого для запуска приложения - это норма. Для решения этой проблемы и делаются инсталляторы. Кстати, вы случаем не Debug-сборку пытались перенести?

Comment: неа, сборка была Realease.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight что такое инсталляторы, можно док или ссылку какую о чем вы говорите ?

Comment: @Dev18 С помощью программ типа [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org) можно создать инсталлятор, который будет устанавливать сначала необходимую версию .NET, а затем само приложение.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight *сначала необходимую версию .NET* Викс обновляет и подправляет пакеты/версии ? что такое необходимая версия ? ошибка, которую получал пользователь, конфликт версий ? а русская версия есть такого ?

Comment: @Dev18 У вас то в чем проблема, почему вы спрашиваете в комментариях в древнему вопросу? У автора ошибка из-за того, что его приложение требует .NET Framework 4.6, а на машине, где он пытался его запустить, эта версия не была установлена. Эту проблему можно решить инсталлятором, но возникает она редко, так как .NET Framework автоматически обновляется через Windows Update.

Comment: @Dev18 русская версия чего? руководства по Wix есть, такое например: https://habr.com/ru/articles/68616/

Comment: Как раз для этого и спрашиваю, был случай когда был конфликт пакетов, и как спрашивающий явручную меняла. А на вопрос случайно наткнулась.и кстати ни раз в древних вопросах ответы нахожу прежде чем задать свой вопрос.